# Cannot plots data in SSH use Linux system

Tags: linux, plot, ssh, gnuplot, x11

I use Linux. I can plot figures in terminal with the command:Gnuplot and Plot...

But when I login to the SSH client from terminal. And I go to Gnuplot. I can not plot data.

Gnuplot show notification is: `'terminal type set to 'unknown'`

Comment: This is a duplicate answer. To question answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/710783/gnuplot-terminal-set-unknown).

Comment: Do you use the option -X of ssh ? (ssh -X .....)

Answer (score 0):

This question answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/710783/gnuplot-terminal-set-unknown.) in sister forum.